# Move contents of an entire folder to external VIA

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file to move an entire folder and it's contents over to an external hard drive, and creating a folder with the date.

at the moment, i'm working on only a test file before trying the entire folder.

here is what i've got:

```
net stop MSSQLSERVER
Set FDate=%Date:~-10,10%
Set Fdate=%FDate:/=-%
MOVE C:\ShaiyaServer\ H:\Daryl\Server Backups\%FDate%\
PAUSE
```

I know for a fact my `%FDate%` contains the right formatting.. But my error is:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net stop MSSQLSERVER
The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is not started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3521.

C:\Windows\system32>Set FDate=05/02/2013

C:\Windows\system32>Set Fdate=05-02-2013

C:\Windows\system32>MOVE C:\ShaiyaServer\ H:\Daryl\Server Backups\05-02-2013\
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Windows\system32>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What is my syntax error? And this is being ran with Admin rights

and i am aware that my MSSQLSERVER Service is not started, this is because I haven't started it up again since the first run

By the way.. My folder tree for C:\ShaiyaServer is located here: http://pastebin.com/G0Sse0uA

This is too long to post onto a question. But basically, I have sub-folders and each sub folder is populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are approaching this the wrong way, I looked over your file tree; and you have alot of files in one directory.. So running this in batch take over some time.

```
net stop MSSQLSERVER
Set FDate=%Date:~-10,10%
Set Fdate=%FDate:/=-%
xcopy /s /e c:\ShaiyaServer\*.* H:\Daryl\Server Backups\%FDate%\
net start MSSQLSERVER
PAUSE
```

This will move each file over individually to it's Original folder

Sorry. My Original was too compilicated. See my edit.. Also you might want to consider logging the progress

**Update By Request**

This script only copies the files to your destination not actually move & deletes from the original

Comment: This will not *move* the files, however. I.e. it will not delete them after copying.

Comment: In the OPS Batch code given, he is "moving" over to a new Volume, by windows default.. It does not move, it deletes when migrating over to a new volume.. I have made my batch file, act as windows does.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. The OP has specified MOVE, meaning they want the files to be deleted after migrating. And indeed MOVE does delete files after copying them (regardless of whether the target drive is the same or different from the source, I don't know why you mentioned that). MOVE would have worked for the OP if it were able to reproduce the tree structure. As it is, they do indeed have to use XCOPY, like in your answer (or ROBOCOPY if they are on Win7), but they probably still want the files to be deleted after copying.

Comment: Why did I come out with that? Grab a file on C:\ and drag it to a new location on C:\. It does get moved / deleted. -- Now grab the same file, and move it over to an external source.. It copies and the original remains in intact. --- Instead of b****ing about it.. Produce your own answer if you disagree with mine?

Comment: Drag & drop has nothing to do with CLI. You can make a few simple tests to see that.

Comment: Last part of my comment still stands. Disagree with mine.. Produce your own and then let the OP Decide.

Comment: I do not entirely disagree with your answer, I've merely pointed out a certain drawback, that's all. There's nothing I would be adding in my version to yours except a command (or a series of commands) to remove the source tree's contents.

Comment: True true; but with these "Shaiya" Private servers, they need to be retained in C:\ShaiyaServer or D:\ShaiyaServer -- for them to function, moving them to H:\ as the OP has stated will cause the server to stop working all together. Furthermore, if he has to stop the MSSQL service to move over the databases; then they are attached and possibly in use, moving over the databases when attached in my experience, causes horrible error msg boxes

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realise they could be copying the actual database files. Somehow I thought those would be only backups, which are safe (and to an extent, rather natural) to be moved to a different location. We may not know that for sure but I agree that it is much safer to assume your view on the matter. Still, you should probably not say that your script moves files when in fact it only copies them. :)

Comment: This is great. Sorry for not specifing my needs in the question, but your assumptions are spot on! thankyou